# Reactive Pull with muti-threaded RxJava

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am trying to build a **reactive pull** observer in **RxJava**.

My observer is like so:

```
Observable<Command> myObs = Observable.create(s -> {
   Command command;
   int i = 0;
   do {
      command = NetworkOperation1.call(i);
      logger.info("Init command " + i);
      s.onNext(command);
      i++;
   } while (!command.isLast() && i < MAX);
   s.onCompleted();
});
```

And I want to process it in 4 concurrent batches (buffer), like so:

```
myObs
    .buffer(10)
    .flatMap(batch -> {
          return Observable
                   .from(batch)
                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                   .map(c -> {
                       Intermediate m = NetworkOperation2.call(c));
                       logger.info("Done intermediate " + m.id);
                       return m;
                   }
          }, 4);
```

And then, I need to batch the results in a different size, like so:

```
    .buffer(25)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .subscribe(list ->
         logger.info("Finished batch with " + list.size());
```

The problem is that the Commands in the Observable **are processed all at once**, while I want them to be processed **as they are needed**.

Here is the log of what happens: (notice all 1000 commands are run at once, instead of called as needed)

```
Init command 0
Init command 1
Init command 2
...
Init command 999
Done intermediate 0
Done intermediate 1
...
Done intermediate 24
Finished batch with 25
Done intermediate 25
Done intermediate 26
...
Done intermediate 49
Finished batch with 25
...
```

**QUESTION**: Is there a way to pause the thread of the Observer so it doesn't emmit all the commands at once or something like this? I have tried the request() operator but I can't get it to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need backpressure aware sources and operators. The operators you are using support backpressure but your source does not.

Do this instead:

```
myObs = Observable.range(1,1000)
    .map(i -> NetworkOperation1.call(i));
```

`Observable.range` supports backpressure so will only emit when requested to do so.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I cannot use the `Observable.range` in this case. Is it possible to implement a custom source like the one in the question which _supports backpressure_?

Comment: @Darkean why can't you use the standard source operators (range, from, just)?

Comment: If you can use Observable.create(new AbstractOnSubscribe() {...}) then you will get backpressure support out of the box. Have a look at AbstractOnSubscribe.

Comment: @akarnokd I can't use the standard operators because I don't know the number of emissions before it begins. Each command determines if the sequence continues (updated the observer to reflect this). I would like `s.onNext(c)` to block until more can be processed. Does this make sense or should I rethink the process?

Comment: @DaveMoten ok! the AbstractOnSubscribe looks like what I need, will test tonight. Thanks for the tech support guys ;)